# CakePHP show custom validation message on empty fields

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm searching a way to show custom message declared on validation array inside a notEmpty rule.
So if i have this validation:

```
'username' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'username empty',
            'required' => true
        ),
        //other validation rules
```

if i leave e filed empty into form, cake php show his own default message for empty field, and not my custom message. How can i show it and catch this event into my Controller class?

Answer (score 1):

The key to the array should be the fieldname, unless I'm misunderstanding your context:

```
'myFieldName' => array(
           'rule' => 'notEmpty',
           'message' => 'custom message for empty field',
           'required' => true
       )
```

If I've misunderstood the context, please edit your question giving a little bigger picture of the validation code in your model.

Comment: i've edited my question. I've only extract the portion of validation rule about not empty field, because my field has multiple rules

Comment: Try with `required => false`